# Слово "так" и части речи

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, слово **"так"** будет являться междометием, если оно одно употреблено с восклицательным знаком?

*Скажут: всё это не дух разъединения, а дух полупросвещения или полуобразованности. Так! Но ведь все эти люди получили первоначальное образование если не довольно глубокое, то довольно многостороннее: словесник учился ещё в школе математике, а математик — словесности.*

В предложении: *"Так велико разъединение, царствующее между этими представителями разных классов одного и того же общества!"* слово **"так"** будет выступать как усилительная частица или как местоименное наречие с повышенной эмоциональной интонацией?

Answer (score 3):

В тексте слово ТАК употреблено как самостоятельный синтаксический элемент, поэтому возникает двусмысленность.

1. Вы соглашаетесь с утверждением, выраженным в первом предложении. В этом случае ТАК - местоименное наречие со значением "да, это  так".
2. ТАК вы употребляете как начало возражения, в значении "стоп, подождите". Обычно после ТАК в этом случае идёт глагол в форме повелительного наклонения. В этом стучае ТАК - междометие.

   ***Так, подождите. Я, кажется, совсем потерялся. Кто Петя?*** [Андрей Геласимов. Год обмана (2003)] - пример из Нацкорпуса.

Скорей всего, Вы употребили ТАК во втором значении, как междометие.

В словарях по поводу этого слова много информации, но часто словарные статьи, приводя похожие примеры, "спорят" между собой о морфологической принадлежности слова. Это и наречие, и частица, и союз. Как междометие ТАК тоже иногда рассматривается.

Тем интереснее Ваш вопрос.